A numerical integral in multiple variables
I need to evaluate numerical integrations of the form:
$$\begin{align}
I_0 &= \mathbb{E} \left[ \prod_{j}\cosh^{-m}(x_j) \right] \\
I_1(k) &= \mathbb{E} \left[ \tanh(x_k) \prod_{j}\cosh^{-m}(x_j) \right] \\
I_2(k,l) &= \mathbb{E} \left[ \tanh(x_k)\tanh(x_l) \prod_{j}\cosh^{-m}(x_j) \right]
\end{align}$$
where $m\ge0$ is a real parameter. The expectations $\mathbb E[\cdot]$ are taken under the random variables $\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_N) \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, which have a multivariate normal distribution with given means and covariances:
$$\mathbb E[x_i] = u_i,\quad
\mathbb E[(x_i-u_i)(x_j-u_j)] = C_{ij}$$
If we denote this multivariate normal distribution of $\mathbf x$ by $\mathcal N(\mathbf x)$, we may write:
$$I_0 = \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf x \, \mathcal N(\mathbf x) \prod_{j}\cosh^{-m}(x_j)$$
$$\dots$$
and so on.
Note that $\mathcal N(\mathbf x) \prod_{j}\cosh^{-m}(x_j)$ is a log-concave function of $\mathbf x$ (recall $m\ge0$). So I can easily find things like where its only maximum likes by fast numerical optimization, the curvature (i.e. Hessian) around this minimum, and so on. I also know that as $x_i \rightarrow\infty$, that $\cosh^{-m}(x_i) \sim \exp(-m |x_i|)$,  in which case the integration is closely related to the outhunt probabilities of a multivariate normal (see Computing the orthant probability of multivariate normal). In turn, the factors $\tanh(x_k)$ are bounded, smooth, and monotonous. These nice properties give me hope that a good numerical integration procedure could be found, but of course this is just wishful thinking.
I have tried Monte-Carlo, but it seems difficult to get accurate results with a reasonable number of samples. So I would like to explore deterministic cubature approaches. I have tried some adaptive methods available in numerical packages (specifically https://github.com/JuliaMath/HCubature.jl) but they seem too slow. My guess is that blindly trying generic methods is not exploiting enough the above listed properties of the integrand. I don't have a lot of experience with Cubature methods (I am doing some reading), so I'm open to suggestions of what methods I could try.

Have you tried quasi-monte carlo? What's the dimension $N$ equal to here?

@lightxbulb I'm interested in $N$ from 2 to 5 or 10. Do you have any particular method in mind?

As far as low discrepanvy sequences go you can try Hammersley, Halton, Sobol, R2 (https://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/).
But for $2\leq N \leq 5$ cubatures are probably also fine.

I've been trying nested Gaussian-Hermite quadrature, and it seems to be working fine. Though I bet this is is far from the optimal solution here.
