Computing the orthant probability of multivariate normal
Let $\mathbf x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf u, C)$ be a random vector following a multivariate normal distribution, with given means and covariances:
$$\mathbb E[x_i] = u_i,\quad \mathbb E[(x_i-u_i)(x_j-u_j)] = C_{ij}$$
What is the probability that all the components of $\mathbf x$ are positive? That is, we want to compute the integral:
$$P_+ = \int_0^\infty p(\mathbf x)\mathrm{d}\mathbf x$$
where $p(\mathbf x)$ is the probability density function of $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf u, C)$. Note that $P_+$ is a function of the parameters of the multivariate normal distribution, $\mathbf u, C$.
Except in some particular cases (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334212/normal-multivariate-orthant-probabilities), there is no closed-form expression for $P_+$. So I'm interested in good numerical cubature algorithms to obtain good approximations of $P_+$. Are there good computational methods to get accurate estimates of $P_+$?

Related: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44785/a-numerical-integral-in-multiple-variables

How is this different from computing any other statistic of $p(x)$, for which methods are well described?

@WolfgangBangerth Obviously not all statistics are equally easy to compute, don't you agree? Any statistic in any distribution can be mapped to computing an appropriate statistic under a normal distribution (i.e. by importance sampling). So I'm asking about methods for one particular kind of statistic. Does that make sense?

Also, if you can suggest some literature on computing normally distributed statistic, I'd be happy to take a look, probably I missed some !
